# Filter Application Based on IdentifierURIs

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

**I'm trying to filter application using Graph API:**

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications?$filter=identifierUris/any(c:c eq 'https://testingSAML.com')
```

**It returns the application details. But when I try with:**

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications?$filter=identifierUris/any(c:c eq 'security-saml')
```

**It returns nothing.**

I tried to create an app and added identifierURIs value like security-saml, https://testingSAML.com, etc .
I able to add value to the identifierURIs but when I try to filter with "**security-saml**", it is not working but it is working for "**https://testingSAML.com**".

Whether I am missing anything here?

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results***

I registered one Azure AD B2C application and added same `identifierURIs` as you but got **error** like below:

```json
"identifierUris": ["https://testingSAML.com","security-saml"],
```

[image]

If I change that to only `security-saml`, I'm getting different **error** like below:

[image]

> You can check the **supported** `identifierUris` formats from this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps#identifieruris-attribute). In B2C tenants, it's necessary to have either `https://` or `api://` as **prefix** to add identifierURIs.

I assume  `https://testingSAML.com` is your **custom domain** and you are in normal Azure AD directory, so it worked for you. In my case, I changed it to *tenant name* by appending string at end like below:

```json
"identifierUris": ["https://tenantname.onmicrosoft.com/<string>"],
```

[image]

To add `security-saml` too, I appended **api://** before it like below:

[image]

Now I tried to *filter* the applications from **Graph API** and got results successfully like below:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications?$filter=identifierUris/any(c:c eq 'https://tenantname.onmicrosoft.com/testingSAML')
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I tried to filter with only `security-saml`, I got **blank** results like below:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications?$filter=identifierUris/any(c:c eq 'security-saml')
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I tried filtering applications with ***api://security-saml***, I got the results successfully like below:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications?$filter=identifierUris/any(c:c eq 'api://security-saml')
```

**Response:**

[image]

Make sure to **switch** your directory to B2C tenant before registering application and add `identifierURIs` by considering the ***supported*** formats.

Comment: Under App Manifest, find the accessTokenAcceptedVersion parameter and set the value to 2, this will allow you to put any random value to the identifierURis. 

Yes I am using Azure AD B2C tenant and following below URL to register SAML application.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/saml-service-provider?pivots=b2c-custom-policy&tabs=macos

Comment: Actually, accessTokenAcceptedVersion parameter is set to 2 by default and AFAIK, URIs with `https://` or `api://` as prefix only works

Comment: Under Supported account types, select Accounts in this organizational directory only. You might have selected the last option (User flow type).

Comment: This is how Azure B2C SAML works, it support local login. That part is already working fine, I just have a concern over how to filter out based on normal value of identifierURIs as it is allowing to store but not filter it.

Comment: AFAIK, filtering with **random** string of identifierURIs is not supported and works only with URIs having `https://` or `api://` as prefix.

Comment: This is what I want to understand, if random string allowed then why not it supported in filtering.